# NSBundle Why console output (null)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

> main.m  for test

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bookinf"
                                                         ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:nil];
    NSLog(@"file content : %@" , content);
```

> bookinf.txt Content : '<'The C Programming Language>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug it a step at a time. `pathForResource` returns nil if it can't find the file. Then `stringWithContentsOfFile` will fail (Not sure if it will return nil or crash) if `filePath` is nil.

As Anbu says in his answer, the most likely cause is that you did not set up the file to be included in the app bundle. Assuming you added the file to your project, check in the file inspector and make sure that your app is checked under "target membership"